# Is there a way to get Project Spartan on Windows 10 via offline update?

Tags: windows

As the title states, I'm trying to get the latest build for Windows 10 technical preview so I can evaluate our internal web sites with Spartan. Apparently the latest build (10049) is not available as an ISO, so I have to get it via the Windows Update functionality. I've set up a VM with VMware Player and configured it to use NAT, browsing works fine, but Windows Update is not working at all. According to the error code names cannot be resolved, seems to work fine for browsing with IE though, which is properly configured to use a proxy.
So is there any way to install the Project Spartan browser via an installer/offline update or do I have to wait until there is an ISO?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create an ISO based on the ESD file](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/instructions-create-a-bootable-iso-file-using-esd/1d64c65c-f619-4193-9bce-d6ed5d3b66da) with the help of the tool **ESD Decrypter**.

Now install a clean Windows 10 VM.

Comment: Thanks a lot, unfortunately the resources are not available under the mentioned links, so I cannot test it. I'll try again later, apparently the data is just not available yet.

Comment: ok, I haven't checked the links. I'm still at 10041 because MS has not released newer developer tools. Maybe MS pulled the download because of the MUI issue where all MUIs were installed during upgrade from 10041. There is a leak of Build 10051 which also includes Spartan. Try this build.